# C Unix socket programming, ensuring read/write byte counts?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm writing client and server programs and I'm looking for a way to ensure all bytes are read and all bytes are sent when using read() or write() to/from the sockets opened by the client/server.

I'm assuming I'll have to use a loop to check the number of bytes returned from the read or write functions.

Something like this probably:

```
#define BUFFER 20
char buffer[BUFFER];

while (I haven't read all bytes from the buffer){
       int bytesRead = read(theSocket, myWord, BUFFER);
 }
```

And how would I ensure that all the bytes I am trying to transmit using write() have been transmitted?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Exactly the same way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly like that. Typical read logic goes like this:

1) Call `read`.

2) Did we get EOF or error? If so, return.

3) Did we receive all the bytes? If so, return.

4) Go to step 1.

Note that when you call `read`, you'll need to pass it a pointer to the buffer after the data that was already read, and you'll need to try to read an appropriate amount of bytes that won't overflow the buffer. Also, how you tell if you received all the bytes depends on the protocol.

To write:

1) Call `write`, passing it a pointer to the first unwritten byte and the number of unwritten bytes.

2) Did we get zero or error? If so, return.

3) Did we write all the bytes? If so, return.

4) Go to step 1.

Note that you have to adjust appropriately for blocking or non-blocking sockets. For example, for non-blocking sockets, you have to handle `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

The only question I still have is how to determine the number of bytes to check for when using the read() function(step 3 above) if you don't know the exact amount you should be receiving.  Should the sending side start the message with the number of expected bytes so the receiving side can use the first byte to determine the length(in bytes) of the rest of the message?

Write() is obviously easy to test for because the message being sent can be seen by the writing process.

Comment: You should follow the specification for the protocol you are implementing. If it says the sender should prefix messages with the number of expected bytes, you should do that. If it says messages terminate with a CRLF, then you should do that. Follow the specification. (And if it's your own protocol, it's well worth the effort to make a proper specification and then follow that.)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm using tcp by the way, I wasn't sure if I even had to check but I couldn't find any answers with quick google searches. I'll spend some more time researching.

Comment: Using TCP to implement what protocol though? These kinds of things are determined by the protocol you are implementing as much as the protocol you are employing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - can send() ever return 0 ?  And if it did, would that necessarily be considered an error in either a blocking or non-blocking socket?

Comment: If send() returns 0, that means the connection has closed normally, blocking or non-blocking.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - that is not consistent with my observations nor is it called out in the man page. My observation for TCP sockets is taht attempting to call send on a socket that has been closed remotely will result in -1 being returned and errno set to EPIPE. However, recv() will return 0 to indicate a socket that was closed or shutdown remotely. So I'm still left wondering if there's a legit case where send can return 0. At present, I treat it as an error condition.

Comment: @selbie: The [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/send.html) clearly indicates that a return value of `0` indicates success, not failure, but that zero bytes have been sent. However, `EPIPE` is a *shall fail* indication if the local end is shut down. Thus, a return value of 0 means no bytes sent, and no error, but the local end is not shut down. This could theoretically occur with a protocol that had different half-closed semantics compared to TCP, but there's no way it can happen with TCP. Rememeber, `send` has protocol-neutral semantics, it's not TCP-specific.